# CSS Onmouseover rotate child element

Tags: css, rotation

I have in the following code that when you mouse over the clid element, it is rotating.
I want the parent and the child to trigger the rotation when hovering.

https://jsfiddle.net/d4sbvmb0/

```css
.parent {
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  background: silver;
  padding: 25px;
}

.child {
  background: red;
  border-radius: 2% 50%;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 100px;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  width: 100px;
}

.child:hover {
  transform: rotate(20deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you asking to rotate the child when the parent is hovered? Is it supposed to rotate an additional amount if both the parent and child are rotated?

Comment: like this? https://jsfiddle.net/d4sbvmb0/1/

Comment: You gonna need JS to trigger the hover of parent when you mouseover the child. You can do that with event bubbling

Answer (score 0):

If you only need the parent element to trigger the rotation of the child simply modify the selector containing the transform from `.child:hover` to `.parent:hover .child`. With the latter we are saying, when the `.parent` is hovered, select the `.child` and rotate it.

```css
.parent {
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  background: silver;
  padding: 25px;
}

.child {
  background: red;
  border-radius: 2% 50%;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 100px;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  width: 100px;
}

.parent:hover .child {
  transform: rotate(20deg);
}

/* Add me if you want additional rotation when both are hovered. */
/*
.parent:hover .child:hover {
  transform: rotate(40deg);
}
*/
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

**Note:** `transition-timing` should be `transition-timing-function`.

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
.parent:hover .child {
    transform: rotate(20deg);
}
```